# Get response from facebook API

Tags: ruby, facebook, networking, get, request

I am trying to use the Facebook API to make get_requests. This is my code.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/156262626262/comments'
uri = URI(url)
token = "xxxxxxxxxx"
request = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri+'?access_token='+token)
p request.body
```

However it returns following Json.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "FXDzDubQ743"
   }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm guessing that either my token is wrong or the way I'm sending my get request is formatted wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're using an invalid access token. Are you actually using "xxxxxxxxxx" or are you getting a proper access token from somewhere?

Comment: Of course I got a proper access token.